# Rails devise keep user logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise, omniauth

I am using a GEM device to authenticate user from Facebook oauth. I use the following to create a user

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
  user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
  unless user
    user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                       provider:auth.provider,
                       uid:auth.uid,
                       email:auth.info.email,
                       password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                       )
  end
  user
 end
```

and then to login:

```
def facebook

  @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    return '/mypage'
  end

  if @user.persisted?
    flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
    sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
  else
    session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```

However when the user visits the app after about 15 minutes of inactivity they will no longer be logged in. How can I increase this time? I don't seem to be getting anywhere currently.

If anyone could provide details of setting a cookie or something so that this will persist even when the browser is closed that would be good to.

EDIT

Full user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
       :omniauthable
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :name,  :provider, :uid, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :ratings
  has_many :rated_recipes, :through => :ratings, :source => :recipes

  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    unless user
      user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                       provider:auth.provider,
                       uid:auth.uid,
                       email:auth.info.email,
                       password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                       )
    end
    user
  end
end
```

EDIT:

So some of the advice below has got me somewhere. It all seems to work fine when you access the rails via the url it is hosted at. However as soon as you hit the facebook app page the user no longer persists in any of the tabs open. Can't see why this would be

Comment: Could you paste your `user.rb` ?

Comment: If you are using `timeoutable` Devise module, then you may want to check `config.timeout_in` option in your `RAILS_APP/config/initializers/devise.rb`. By default it's set to 30 minutes.

Comment: Apart for devise config you can set it dynamically as well. Check this link https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-timeout_in-value-dynamically

Comment: Both seem like excellent answers. Thanks for your help. I will add an answer to this unless unless anyone else cares to. Many thanks for your help

Comment: So some of the advice above has got me somewhere. It all seems to work fine when you access the rails via the url it is hosted at. However as soon as you hit the facebook app page the user no longer persists in any of the tabs open. Can't see why this would be